# A Server restarted and Website giving 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

So i was asked to check this server out that after a restart is giving an 502 bad gateway message.

It's an nginx 1.10.3 in an ubuntu

I was looking around and what I can see is this:

in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

`2020/03/18 02:29:45 [error] 3166#3166: *474 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 190.162.83.37, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/500.html", host: "domain.website.com"`

I see this error multiple times. All I was told is that the website was working fine until it was rebooted. Apparently the server had been working non-stop for months.

The nginx.conf config is:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        uwsgi_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

And the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file:

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 172.31.0.59;

  root /home/ubuntu/xxx/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt|A8774B2003352D7DCA9406C3FADC610B.txt|sitemap.xml|video.mp4 {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 172.31.0.59;
  ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/cert/demain.website.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/cert/demain.website.com.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


  #maintenance
  error_page 503 /maintenance.html;

  location /maintenance.html {
    # allow access to this specific page
  }

  #location / {
  #  return 503;
  #}

  # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
  root /home/ubuntu/xxx/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;

 }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt|A8774B2003352D7DCA9406C3FADC610B.txt|sitemap.xml|video.mp4 {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  # Turn on Passenger
  #passenger_enabled on;
  #passenger_ruby /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby;
  #passenger_app_env stage;
 }
```

I don't know what to do. Please Help.

Comment: can you make sure the socket is there. ` ls /home/ubuntu/xxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock `? NGINX can't send the proxy request to the upstream server. Therfore it isn' starting.

Comment: What I see in this: ubuntu:~/norwegian/shared/tmp/sockets ls
puma.sock=  sockets@